# How to find max value without Lagrange

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum values of the function $$f(x,y,z)=2x-y+4z$$ on the unit sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$, but without using langrange multipliers or gradient. I would like to do this basically only using geometric properties, dot product etc.

My thoughts are this could maybe be done using  $$u \bullet v = ||u||||v||cos\theta$$

but I am not sure if my reasoning is correct.

say $u=(2,-1,4)$ and $v=(x,y,z)$ then would have a max value when v is orthogonal to use, that is when $\theta=0$ and a min when $\theta=\pi$ for example?

Looking for any help/suggestions etc,

Ps, it can still use regular calculus such as partials , vector etc

thanks

Comment: $f$ is the $\cdot$ product of $X=(x,y,z)$ and $V=(2,-1,4)$. We know that $|X\cdot V|\leq \|X\|\|V\|$. This is Cauchy's inequality. And we know that the equality is obtained when the vectors are co-linear. Since $X$ is in the sphere we know that $\|X\|=1$. Therefore you get maximum when $X=V/\|V\|$.

Comment: The gradient is a geometric property

Comment: @Nathanson, in my view you should convert that to an answer.

Comment: @Nathanson Yes if you could answer with that thatd be great. That is exactly the type of thing I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is the $\cdot$ product of $X=(x,y,z)$ and $V=(2,−1,4)$. We know that $|X\cdot V|\leq\|X\|\|V\|$. This is Cauchy's inequality,for which we know that the equality is obtained when the vectors are co-linear. Since $X$ is in the sphere we know that $\|X\|=1$. Therefore $|X\cdot V|\leq \|V\|$.

The vectors that are co-linear with $V$  and are in the sphere are $X=-\frac{1}{\|V\|}V$ and $X=\frac{1}{\|V\|}V$. For the latter you get the maximum $\left(\frac{1}{\|V\|}V\right)\cdot V=\|V\|$.

But this is pretty much the same argument you were giving in the question.

Comment: Thank you. But just how about do you go solving for X. I mean how did you get those solutions precisely?

Comment: @PersonaA A vector co-linear with $V$ is of the form $aV$, with $a$ scalar. Since it must be on the unit sphere then $1=\|aV\|=|a|\|V\|$. Therefore $|a|=\frac{1}{\|V\|}$, i.e. $a=\pm\frac{1}{\|V\|}$.

Comment: I see, so to find the actual answer, do I use that with the normal $N=(2,-1,4)$, that is $f(x,y,z)$ is the max when $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt21} , y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt21}$ etc, I am still a bit confused?

Comment: @PersonaA Yes, when $X=(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\|V\|}V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{21}}(2,-1,4)=$$(\frac{2}{\sqrt{21}},$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{21}},\frac{4}{\sqrt{21}})$. This is, when $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{21}}$, $y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{21}}$ and $z=\frac{4}{\sqrt{21}}$.

Comment: Thank you sir. Just also wondering, is it equivlent to say colinear as saying $cos(\theta)$ = 0 or pi ?

Answer (score 2):

W/O using Calculus,

Let $x=\cos A\sin B,y=\cos A\cos B,z=\sin A$

$f(x,y,z)=2x-y+4z=\cos A(2\sin B-\cos B)+4\sin A$

$=\sqrt5\cos A\sin\left(B-\sin^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt5}\right)+4\sin A$

If $\displaystyle\cos A\ge0,f\le\sqrt5\cos A+4\sin A=\sqrt{21}\sin\left(A+\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{21}}\right)\le\sqrt{21}$

If $\displaystyle\cos A<0,f\ge-\sqrt5\cos A+4\sin A=\sqrt{21}\sin\left(A-\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{21}}\right)\ge-\sqrt{21}$